# TDS buffer length too large

Tags: sql-server, informatica-powercenter

I have an Informatica 9.1 session receiving a Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error "TDS buffer length too large" from a SQL Server 2008R2 database server.  I've found some old references to this kind of a problem but everything is dated to a much earlier version of SQL Server.  I was wondering if anyone had seen something similar.  The server is host on VMWare Vsphere 5.X.  All of the guest OS servers involved are running on Windows 2008 and should be using MDAC 2.8.  Any help would be appreciated.  At this point I'm just trying to figure out where to start looking?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

It resolved my problem, hope it does for you too:

1. On the Database Server Right Click "Network" -> Properties
2. Right Click Local Area Connection -> Properties
3. Select Internet Protocol(TCP/IP) -> Configure
4. Go to Advanced Tab -> Speed & Duplex, if the **value** is "auto", set the value to -> "**100mb full**"